# How to solve this type of PDE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, problem-solving

I need to solve this differential equation, $\beta$ is constant:

$0=4\beta\dfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial r^2}+\dfrac{4\beta}{r}\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial r}$

I don`t know what to do with $\dfrac{1}{r}$ in the second term on the right side, because partial differential is with $r$ in the same term?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$0=4\beta\dfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial r^2}+\dfrac{4\beta}{r}\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial r}$$
First, why don't you simplify ? (I suppose $\beta\neq 0$. If not, this is trivial).
$$0=\dfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial r^2}+\dfrac{1}{r}\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial r}$$
Second, there is only one variable $r$. Why don't you write it as a simple ODE ?
$$0=\dfrac{d^2 u}{d r^2}+\dfrac{1}{r}\dfrac{d u}{d r}$$
$v=\frac{d u}{d r} \quad\to\quad 0=\dfrac{d v}{d r}+\frac{1}{r}v \quad\to\quad \frac{dv}{v}=-\frac{dr}{r}\quad\to\quad v=\frac{c_1}{r}$
$$u=\int v\,dr=\int \frac{c_1}{r}\,dr$$

$$u(r)=c_1\ln|r|+c_2$$
$c_1$ and $c_2$ are any constants.

Supposing that there is a second hidden variable (for example $t$) :
$$u(r,t)=c_1(t)\ln|r|+c_2(t)$$
$c_1(t)$ and $c_2(t)$ are any functions of $t$.
$$ $$

IN ADDITION, after the comments :

The PDE to be solved is :
$$4\beta\dfrac{\partial^2 u(r,z)}{\partial r^2}+\dfrac{4\beta}{r}\dfrac{\partial u(r,z)}{\partial r} =\dfrac{\partial p(z)}{\partial z} \tag 1$$
Why do you write $\dfrac{\partial p(z)}{\partial z}$ instead of $\frac{dp}{dz}$ ? Since $p(z)$ is a function of one variable only.

Let $\frac{dp}{dz}=g(z)$
$$4\beta\dfrac{\partial^2 u(r,z)}{\partial r^2}+\dfrac{4\beta}{r}\dfrac{\partial u(r,z)}{\partial r} =g(z)$$
There is no derivative with respect to $z$, thus this is an ODE involving the variable $r$ only.

Let $U(r)=u(r,z)$ with $z$ not a variable, but a simple parameter : 
$$4\beta U''+\dfrac{4\beta}{r}U' =g$$
It is easy to solve this second order linear ODE.
$$U(r)=\frac{1}{16\beta}r^2g+c_1\ln(r)+c_2$$
The general solution of thev PDE $(1)$ is :
$$u(r,z)=\frac{1}{16\beta}r^2\frac{dp}{dz}+c_1(z)\ln(r)+c_2(z)$$
$c_1(z)$ and $c_2(z)$ are arbitrary functions, to be determined according to the boundary conditions.

If the conditions are : $r=0: \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial r}=0$ and $r=1: u=0$

The first condition implies $c_1(z)=0$.

The second condition $0=\frac{1}{16\beta}1^2\frac{dp}{dz}+c_2(z)$ implies $c_2(z)=-\frac{1}{16\beta}\frac{dp}{dz}$

So, according to the conditions, the solution is :
$$u(r,z)=\frac{1}{16\beta}r^2\frac{dp}{dz}-\frac{1}{16\beta}\frac{dp}{dz}$$
$$u(r,z)=\frac{1}{16\beta}(r^2-1)\frac{dp}{dz}$$

Comment: Thank you, exactly my equation is: $\dfrac{\partial p}{\partial z}=4\beta \dfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial r^2}+\dfrac{4 \beta}{r}\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial r}$, left side is not dependent on the right side, so I can see it here as a constant. But I cannot simplify it without $4 \beta$, even if I would first solve it as equation $0=4\beta \dfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial r^2}+\dfrac{4 \beta}{r}\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial r}$ and then add particular solution in of constant, am I right?   On the other side, what can I do when $u=u(z,r)$, can I substitute particular derivatives with usual derivatives?

Comment: As a result, when I don`t make equation shorten with $4\beta$ I got: $u=\dfrac{r^{-4\beta+1}}{-4\beta+1}C+C_1$, and with particular solution that would be: $u=\dfrac{r^{-4\beta+1}}{-4\beta+1}C+C_1 +C_p$, am I right?

Comment: $u=\frac{r^{-4\beta+1}}{-4\beta+1}C+C_1$ is NOT solution of $0=4\beta\dfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial r^2}+\dfrac{4\beta}{r}\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial r}$.

Comment: My PDE:

$4\beta\dfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial r^2} + \dfrac{4\beta}{r}\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial r}=\dfrac{\partial p}{\partial z}$, 

where $\beta$ is constant, and $p=f(z)$, $r$ is radial coordinate, $z$ is longitudinal coordinate and $u=f(r,z)$. 

Additional conditions:
$r=0: \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial r}=0$;
$r=1: u=0$.

I have no idea how special is this equation because of $\dfrac{1}{r}$ in the second term on the left side, so may I substitute that $u=e^{ar}$, where $a$ is constant and solve it as homogenuous equation?

Comment: This is not understandable because the same function $f$ is of two variables in $u=f(r,z)$ and of only one variable in $p=f(z)$.

Comment: See the addition to my first answer.